# How to translate this raw mongodb javascript query into rails mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am new to Mongodb and rails, and I was hoping someone could help me.

I would like to run the equivalent of this mongo .js query in Mongoid:

```
db.getCollection('users').find({interest_ids: { $in: [ObjectId("string")]}}).sort({rank: -1}).limit(100)
```

I have so far done it this way in ruby:

```
users = User.in(interest_ids: ["string"]).order_by(:rank => 'desc').limit(100)
```

This works, but it is very slow.  It doesn't actually do the "in" check until I later resolve it with

users.to_json or something like that.

If i run the query directly in a mongo shell, it is instantaneous and has what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`"string"` and `ObjectId("string")` are not the same thing in the MongoDB shell. `"string"` and `BSON::ObjectId.from_string("string")` are not the same thing when using Mongoid. So the equivalent Mongoid query to your JavaScript one would be:

```
User.in(interest_ids: [BSON::ObjectId.from_string("string")])
    .order_by(:rank => 'desc')
    .limit(100)
```

or:

```
User.where(:interest_ids.in => [BSON::ObjectId.from_string("string")])
    .order_by(:rank => 'desc')
    .limit(100)
```

Mongoid queries don't access the database until you do something with them that forces them to, this matches ActiveRecord's behavior so it should be expected. If you want to force the query to load the documents then say so:

```
User.where(:interest_ids.in => [BSON::ObjectId.from_string("string")])
    .order_by(:rank => 'desc')
    .limit(100)
    .to_a # <-------------------
```

You could also say `.entries` or start iterating over the results with `.each` etc.

The plural name of your field, `interest_ids`, suggests that it is actually an array of `BSON::ObjectId` rather than a single `BSON::ObjectId`. If that's the case, then your MongoDB query should be:

```
db.getCollection('users').find({ interest_ids: ObjectId("string") }).sort({rank: -1}).limit(100)
```

and the Mongoid version would be:

```
User.where(:interest_ids => BSON::ObjectId.from_string("string"))
    .order_by(:rank => 'desc')
    .limit(100)
```

MongoDB will look inside an array field on its own so `{ array_field: scalar_value }` will find all the documents where any of the elements in `array_field` match `scalar_value`.